# Start node.js with bash script?

Tags: node.js, bash, raspberry-pi

What to do when I have to start a node.js application with a script on the raspberry pi?

Normally I go to the command line move to the map with "cd projectMap" and do this command "npm projectName"

I thought this would work but it does not.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd projectMap
npm projectName
```

Answer (score 0):

to run a nodejs script you generally run

```
node index.js
```

Replace index.js with the name of the file you want to run.

To run it with npm you have to add it as a script in the package.json like so

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

And to run it:

```
npm start
```

Comment: This is already what I have but then I have to use the terminal, I want to do it in a script like bash

Answer (score 0):

Create a file:

sudo touch script.sh

Give permission:

sudo chmod 400 script.sh

Inside your script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd project
npm -i
node -v // not necessary just to check the node version .
node file.js
```

run script.sh

./script.sh

Comment: Can I put this on the home screen as a icon and click it to execute?